# Does Java Mac OSX native look and feel respect UIManager font changes?

Tags: java, macos, swing, size, fonts

I have a java applet and the only look and feel that works properly is the native mac one. I wanted to make the fonts a bit larger and tried using the standard UIManager methods

UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 18));

This produces no change. It does not throw an exception, of course.

Does anyone know if the native mac look and feel ignores these?

I know there are specific ways to make controls different sizes on mac but these only seem to make them smaller. You cannot make the controls larger than regular.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to work on Mac OS X with any installed L&F.

Addendum: If you are trying to change the setting after startup, see [*How to Set the Look and Feel*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) under [*Changing the Look and Feel After Startup*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic).

```
public final class Laf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                f.add(new JLabel("Test"));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

public final class LafApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        this.add(new JLabel("Test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be safer to use a FontUIResource instead of a Font. See demo provided.

Comment: I'm doing it a JApplet and I set it in the init and then not changing it. It works with Metal Look and Feel but I accomplished that by creating a child class of metallookand feel. Since two people think this works even with the mac native look and feel I will try it again.

thanks

Comment: It works for all L&Fs in the `JApplet` above, subject to the point raised by @camickr.

Answer (score 1):

The updateComponentTreeUI(...) method (referenced in the Changing the LAF After Startup link provided by trashgod) will only work on a FontUIResource, not a Font. This is only relevant if you need to change the Font multiple times after startup.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class ChangeFont extends JFrame
{
    private int size = 12;
    private JComponent component;

    public ChangeFont()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.append( "updateComponentTreeUI will only work on a FontUIResource\n\n" );
        textArea.append( "1) click the FontUIResource button as many times as you want\n" );
        textArea.append( "2) after you click the Font button, neither button will work" );
        getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton west = new JButton( "FontUIResource" );
        west.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                update( new FontUIResource("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, size) );
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(west, BorderLayout.WEST );

        JButton east = new JButton( "Font" );
        east.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                update( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, size) );
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(east, BorderLayout.EAST );

        component = new JTable(5, 5);
        getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void update(Font font)
    {
        UIManager.put("Table.font", font);
        UIManager.put("TextArea.font", font);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( this );
        size += 2;
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChangeFont frame = new ChangeFont();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know that. Good example!