# Java GTK+ native look and feel looks bad and bold

Tags: java, swing, gtk, look-and-feel

I'm facing a problem when applying a native Look & Feel to my JFrame, all text (except HTML formatted JLabel) have an ugly bold font.

The very simple UI in the following code sum up all the differences I can see with this L&F :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame {
    public HelloWorld() {
        Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Labels
        JLabel bold = new JLabel("I'm bold !");
        JLabel notBold = new JLabel("<html><em>I'm not bold !</em></html>");
        b.add(bold);
        b.add(notBold);

        // Scrollbars example
        JPanel scrollViewPort = new JPanel();
        scrollViewPort.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(scrollViewPort);
        b.add(scroll);

        add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Bold menu
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item");
        menu.add(item);
        menubar.add(menu);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        pack();
    }

    public static void setNativeLAF() {
        // Native L&F
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set native look and feel: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setNativeLAF();

        HelloWorld app = new HelloWorld();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

See the difference :

with native L&F (GTK+)

[image: with native L&F (GTK+)]

with Metal L&F

[image: with Metal L&F]

by commenting out the `setNativeLAF()` call.

I'm applying the native look and feel right when my application starts, before any window appears. The `UIManager` gives me `GTK+ (com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel)` as the native look and feel, which is ok since i'm using a Gnome 3 desktop.

I have three problems with this right now :

1. The GTK+ look and feel doesn't looks like the GTK theme (see the scrollbars)
2. The JMenuBar seems disabled *(not the case with the Metal L&F)*
3. The font is bold ! *(same problem with Metal L&F, but fixable)*

Any help or explanation about why the GTK+ L&F does that on my system whould be appreciated.

Edit: Here is what a "classic" application looks like on my system in eclipse.

[image: eclipse]

Comment: Try http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/themes/

Comment: As for the eclipse screenshot, what 'labels'?  I see a title, menus, tabs, icons, buttons.  Where are the labels?  What text do they contain, and why do I need to ask you?  Your GUI - same basic questions.  Are you referring to the *"Click on a.."* or **"10x10 blocks"**?  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And by that I mean code added to your question, as opposed to a screenshot of it in your IDE. ;)

Comment: please whats happens when you set `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);` is there any difference, as Andrew mentioned your 2nd. screenshot is shot to the dark, on ecplipse sited is described used look and feel for concrete native os

Comment: Since I cannot put more than two links in my question for spam previention, here is the link to show what a "classic" application looks like on my system : [eclipse](http://i.imgur.com/QlUe1.png), which correctly use the GTK3 system theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several things worth mentioning:

1. You can apply a derived font to a label, as shown below.
2. The relevant [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) for [HTML in a component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) sys "**EM** basic emphasis typically rendered in an *italic font*".
3. See also *[Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)*.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame {

    public HelloWorld() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Box b = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Labels
        JLabel bold = new JLabel("I'm bold !");
        bold.setFont(bold.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        JLabel notBold = new JLabel("<html><em>I'm not bold !</em></html>");
        b.add(bold);
        b.add(notBold);

        // Scrollbars example
        JPanel scrollViewPort = new JPanel();
        scrollViewPort.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(scrollViewPort);
        b.add(scroll);
        add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Bold menu
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Item");
        menu.add(item);
        menubar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HelloWorld app = new HelloWorld();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting informations for my rusty Java, thanks ! 

For the record, the emphasized HTML JLabel was here because Metal *does* render it bold, so it seemed relevant for me :
1) Metal renders everything bold by default, even the italic HTML JLabel
2) The GTK+ look and feel behave differently on my system, and doesn't "render every text with a bold style", since the JLabel example shows it's not the case.

Comment: Each L&F has a default font for various components. Metal uses the `Dialog` family with a bold style; I'm not sure about GTK. You can change fonts as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2892721/230513). Sorry, I overlooked the scrollbar issue.